# Having trouble submitting nested resource through form [Rails 5]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-5, nested-resources

I have a `Document` that `has_many` `Section`, and each `section` `has_one` `Comment`. I want to be able to create both `sections` and `comments` in the `Document` `show` view, but I'm having trouble getting `comments` to go through.

Here's the relevant code with the closest I've got:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @section = Section.find(params[:id])
    @section.comment.create(comment_params)
  end

  private

    def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:body)
    end
end
```

The routing:

```
resources :documents, shallow: true do
  resources :sections do
    resources :comments
  end
end
```

And the view with the form:

```
# app/views/documents/show.html.erb

<% @document.sections.each do |section| %>
  <%= section.body %>

  <% if section.comment %>
    <p>
      <%= section.comment %>
    </p>
  <% else %>
    <%= form_with url: section_comments_path(section.id), scope: 'comment' do |form| %>
      <%= form.text_field :body, placeholder: "Comment" %>
      <%= form.submit %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

It all seems to check out for me, but when I try to post a comment, here's what I get:

```
Started POST "/sections/51/comments" for ::1 at 2019-05-24 23:29:06 +0000
Processing by CommentsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>[...], "comment"=>{"body"=>"asdas"}, "commit"=>"Save comment", "section_id"=>"51"}
  Section Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "sections".* FROM "sections" WHERE "sections"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 51], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  comment Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."section_id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["section_id", 51], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 11ms (ActiveRecord: 0.9ms)

NoMethodError (undefined method `create' for nil:NilClass):

app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:4:in `create'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Since comments are nested under sections in your routes, you should find the section in params[:section_id] instead of params[: id] in your create action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `has_one` relationship returns the object itself. Therefore, `@section.comment.create(comment_params)` will not work because `@section.comment` is nil. Instead, try something like...

```
def create
  @section = Section.find(params[:section_id])
  @comment = Comment.create(comment_params)
  @section.comment = @comment

  ...
end
```

Or, as stated in the Rails Guides...

> When initializing a new has_one or belongs_to association you must use
>   the build_ prefix to build the association, rather than the
>   association.build method that would be used for has_many or
>   has_and_belongs_to_many associations. To create one, use the create_
>   prefix.

Which would look like this

```
def create
  @section = Section.find(params[:section_id])
  @section.create_comment(comment_params)

  ...
end
```

Comment: I ended up making some changes and had gotten it to work somehow, so I'm not 100% sure what did it, but I tried it now with `@section.create_comment(comment_params)` and it still works, so I'm accepting the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You likely need to change:

```
@section.comment.create(comment_params)
```

to:

```
@section.comments.create(comment_params)
```

If that doesn't work, try:

```
@section.comment.create!(comment_params)
```

and see what the exception says